# In android device gripped in your hand ,how to measure Wrist movements through the acclerometer or gyrosocpe

Tags: accelerometer, sensors

I am trying to profile the bracelet device to measure the wrist movement through the acclerometer or gyroscope

Comment: Please provid some more info on what device, what code. What did you try etc etc. We can't do anything with this 'question'.

Comment: Hi @stUrb, it's android device I have to measure the wrist movement according to movement to use for Motion gestures.